# R data.table - how to interpolate missing values over FIXED rows in multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, interpolation

```
a = data.table(c(2,NA,3), c(5,NA,1))
```

When I try to interpolate over the missing lines

```
a[, approx(x = 1:.N, y = .SD, xout = which(is.na(.SD))), .SDcols = 1:2]
```

gives the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I wish to get the following:

```
> a
    V1 V2
1: 2.0  5
2: 2.5  3
3: 3.0  1
```

Comment: can you not use `na.approx()` from zoo?

Comment: You could overwrite the full column like `a[, names(a) := lapply(.SD, function(z) approx(.I, z, xout=.I)$y)]` of course, though that might defeat the purpose of using data.table (which allows for editing of part of a column). Note: `.I` is the vector of row numbers for the table.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like `x` and `y` (first two arguments) should be numeric vectors. You'll need to loop through each column.. Here I use `set()` along with a `for-loop` to update the original data.table *by reference*.

```
len = 1:nrow(a)
for (col in names(a)) {
    nas = which(is.na(a[[col]]))
    set(a, i=nas, j=col, value=approx(len, a[[col]], xout=nas)$y)
}
#     V1 V2
# 1: 2.0  5
# 2: 2.5  3
# 3: 3.0  1
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I wonder though, isn't the whole idea of .SD to be the data.table syntax of looping through columns (with .SDcols specifying which columns)? Somehow na.approx() works where approx() does not.